# PyTube yt.download() function doesnt work when opening .py file directly

Tags: python, pytube, ytdl

When I double click the .py file directly, it throws an error and immediately closes.

I really can't understand why running it from cmd works but double clicking, (and thus opening cmd), does not work.

When I open my .py file, I should enter the name of the video, and have its audio downloaded automatically using PyTube.

This is what I wrote:

```py
from pytube import Search

r = Search("hello").results[0]
yt = r.streams.get_audio_only()
yt.download()
```

When I run it using PyCharm, or by opening the Windows command prompt and then typing `python3 ytdl.py`, I get an error:

```
Unexpected renderer encountered.
Renderer name: dict_keys(['reelShelfRenderer'])
Search term: hello
Please open an issue at https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues and provide this log output.
Unexpected renderer encountered.
Renderer name: dict_keys(['reelShelfRenderer'])
Search term: hello
Please open an issue at https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues and provide this log output.
Unexpected renderer encountered.
Renderer name: dict_keys(['adSlotRenderer'])
Search term: hello
Please open an issue at https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues and provide this log output.
```

But it does the job nonetheless, so it doesnt bother me too much

I already checked whether PyTube is installed or not, I ran it on different machines and I always had the same problem.

Comment: what do you get when you run your script on command line?